# Add a new directory in shell script Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

How can I create a new directory by using a function where I pass the directory name as a parameter?

Example:

```
CreateNewDirectory \home\Folder1; # Creates a folder named "Folder1" at home #
```

Comment: Unix does not use backslashes as path separators; it uses slashes (/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo() {
  dirPath=${1:?Need path to directory as first argument}
  mkdir -- "$dirPath"
}
```

Then call:

```
foo /path/to/my/new/directory
```

Comment: @Alfie It might be an idea to add `-p` so OP can add paths like the one you suggest without getting errors if the intermediate directories don't exist.

Comment: Adding features not asked for (which might even veil problems as in this case) is probably not a good idea.  Consider the case where the user passes an argument like `/usr/lacol/lib/newDir` (assuming existing privileges) and then wonders why that expected `/usr/local/lib/newDir` does not exist after the call.  Months later they might find the typo dir `/usr/lacol/` with the rubbish inside.

Comment: Quite a nice idea use `:?`.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this.

```
CreateNewDirectory() {
  mkdir -p "$1"
}

CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and/any/path/in/between
```

It allows you to create complete paths to directories including everything in between. So, even if you do not have a directory called `and` or one called `any` or one called `path` etc, it wil create the entire tree in one go without errors for you, without needing to do

```
CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and
CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and/any
CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and/any/path
CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and/any/path/in
CreateNewDirectory $HOME/and/any/path/in/between
```